# jquery nivo slider caption

Tags: jquery, drupal, nivo-slider

I'm using Drupals Nivo Slider module and want the caption to slide up when the mouse hovers over the sliders div and to disappear when the mouse leaves the div.  I have that figured out but the issue i'm having is the html from the module has inline style of display:block and it makes the caption appear and I don't want the caption to display til someone mouses over it. Right now I have to mouse over it to get rid of the display:block and then it works because of the mouseleave event i'm using.

What is strange is the problem doesn't come up til the third image because the first image doesn't have a caption and the second image does exactly what I want which is not displaying the caption til someone mouses over.  It's the third, fourth and fifth images that display their captions while the images fade in.  I tried adding display:none !important to my css and that makes the captions not appear at all. Here is the my jQuery and any help would be really appreciated and i'm sorry it took so much text to explain my issue.

```
        $('.nivo-caption').css('display', '');

        $('#home_slider').hover(function(){
                $('.nivo-caption p').slideToggle('fast');
        }); 

        $('#home_slider').mouseleave(function(){
                $('.nivo-caption p').css("display", "none");
        });
```

Comment: Still reviewing your question, but first thing.  You can also do

    $('.nivo-caption p').hide();

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    $('.nivo-caption').hide();

    $('#home_slider').hover(
        function(){
            $('.nivo-caption').show('fast');
        },
        function(){
            $('.nivo-caption').hide('fast');
        },
    );
```